# How can I use globally installed AVA for unit tests?

Tags: javascript, ava

I am trying to implement unit testing with AVA for my javascript app.

I have installed AVA globally.

I have created a basic ava.config.cjs file:

```
module.exports = {
    files: ['tests/**', '!tests/**/{fixtures,helpers}/**']
};
```

And I have a test file:

```
import test from 'ava';
// const { test } = require('ava');

test('foo', t => {
    t.pass();
});

test('bar', async t => {
    const bar = Promise.resolve('bar');
    t.is(await bar, 'bar');
});
```

I have tried both 'import', and 'require' but neither work.

When I run ava from the command line I get an error that the module 'ava' can't be found.

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'ava'

Or

> Error: Cannot find module 'ava'

Depending on which method I try to include AVA...

What would I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your machine setup. Node.js here can't find AVA.

That said, installing AVA globally is not recommended. Ideally you install within your project and run with `npx ava` (or preferred-package-manager-equivalent).

Comment: I ended up getting it to work by providing the complete path to the node module:
```import test from '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ava';```...